# Speed up search

Tags: performance, node.js, search, mongoose

I have collection with around 2.5million records. Currently I'm using nodejs with mongoose. I'm open to any suggestions which would improve efficiency of current search.

Artist collection schema is something like that:

```
var Artist = new mongoose.Schema({
    realname: String,
    names: Array
});
```

User passes string for example: *Michael Jackson was contacted by police* or *Michael Jackson-Jillie bean*. Now I have to find artist/singer/person so the only logical thing I could find was: Iterate through all documents in collection, check if any of names is in given string if YES we have match -> stop loop.

But this is very memory inefficient since it has to load whole collection to memory so nodejs can iterate through and check all records.

It seems that retrieving whole collection takes most of time. Any way to speed this up? In mongoshell db.collection.find() is pretty fast. But using mongoose in nodejs takes waaay too long.

- Why is .find() so slow used with mongoose?
- Are there any other databases for designed for this purpose?
- How would you solve this problem more efficiently?
- Could map reduce be for any use here?

Comment: In regard to your specific question about why `find` is so slow with Mongoose, call [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on your `Query` since you only need the data and not full model objects.  It should be about as fast as the shell if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a full-text search. Possible options:

- Use MongoDB [`text` index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes). (new in 2.4)
- Use an addition full text index. In my opinion [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) is very performant and easy to understand for beginners.

Comment: I just briefly checked elasticsearch, and it seems like it works same as SQL %like% operator would. I want just the inverse. I have a long string and now I have to find to which document it would fit the most.

Comment: That's exactly what elasticsearch does (or any other Lucene based solution). There are not databases like MySQL or MongoDB, they are specialized on finding strings or parts of string. In contrast to other databases they do not operate in strings but rather on words and word constructs.